# Docker image size is coming up to 1.7 G for Ubuntu with Python packages

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-image

Following is my Dockerfile :-

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04 AS builder
RUN apt update -y
RUN apt install python3.8 -y && apt install python3-pip -y
RUN apt install build-essential automake pkg-config libtool libffi-dev libgmp-dev -y
RUN apt install libsecp256k1-dev -y 
RUN apt install openjdk-8-jre -y
RUN apt install git -y
RUN apt install libkrb5-dev -y
RUN apt install vim -y
RUN mkdir /opt/app
RUN chown -R root:root /opt/app
COPY ["requirements.txt","/opt/app/requirements.txt"]
SHELL ["/bin/bash", "-c"]
WORKDIR /opt/app
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt && apt-get -y clean all
RUN mkdir /opt/app/
RUN chown -R root:root /opt/app/
RUN cd /opt/app/
RUN git clone -b master https://bitbucket.org/heroes/test.git
CMD ["bash","/opt/app/bin/connect.sh"]
```

Docker image is generating with an image file size of 1.7G. I need to have OpenJDK hence cannot use a standard python package as a base package. When I perform docker history , I can see 2 or 3 layers (installing packages above like Python3.8, OpenJDK and libsecp256k1-dev) taking up to 400MB to 500MB in size. Ubuntu as a base image takes only 64 MB however rest of size is taking by my dockerfile layers.

I believe I need to re-write the dockerfile in order to reduce the file size which I did but nothing happened concrete.

Please assist me on reducing the image less than 1 GB at least.

**[Update]**

Below is my updated Dockerfile:-

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04 AS builder

WORKDIR /opt/app

COPY requirements.txt /opt/app/aws/requirements.txt

RUN mkdir -p /opt/app/aws \
    && apt-get update -yq \
    && apt-get install -y python3.8 python3-pip openjdk-8-jre -yq && apt-get -y clean all \
    && chown -R root:root /opt/app && cd /opt/app/aws && pip3 install -r requirements.txt

FROM alpine
COPY --from=builder /opt/app /opt/app

SHELL ["/bin/bash", "-c"]

CMD ["bash","/opt/app/aws/bin/connector/connect.sh"]
```

Screenshot of image size:-
[image]

After removing unwanted libraries like git, etc and using the multi-stage build, the image is now approx 1.7 GB which I believe is a lot. Any suggestion to improve this?

Comment: why you are using ubuntu image, you can use other small distributions.

Comment: BTW one question why you are using git inside container,  ideally container should have only have build. So I think there is a lot of issues related to architecture

Comment: I need to run apt-get commands to install packages. As I'm more familiar with these commands provided by Ubuntu so I'm using it. I tried to find slim version of Ubuntu but I did not get. Is there any slim linux version where I can use the apt-get commands?

Comment: Use multistage docker build efficiently. That should reduce the actual build size.

Comment: I have used multistage and updated the question with new dockerfile. It is coming around 1.7GB which I believe still more. I would appreciate if you can please have a look and suggest me. Thank you

Comment: It'd help if you can share your `requirements.txt` to replicate the issue.

Answer (score 1):

You have multiple issues going on.

First, each of your `RUN apt install` is increasing your image size, you should have them all in the same RUN stage, and at the end of the stage, delete all cached apt files.

Second, you're installing unnecessary stuff. Why would you need `vim` and `git` for instance? Why are you installing `build-essential` and other build-related stuff if you're not building anything?

Third, it seems you tried to do a multi-stage build but ended up adding everything to the same image. Read up on python multi-stage builds.

Comment: Thanks for looking into it. I'm using git because I clone from a repo then I need git, right?

Comment: I have used multistage and updated the question with new dockerfile. It is coming around 1.7GB which I believe still more. I would appreciate if you can please have a look and suggest me. Thank you

Comment: Cached apt files should be delete automatically. See etc/apt/apt.conf.d/docker-clean in Ubuntu official docker

Answer (score 0):

If we consider best practices instead of multiple `RUN` use single `RUN`.

For example

```
RUN apt-get update -yq \
    && apt-get install -y python3-dev build-essential -yq \
    && apt-get install curl -yq \
    && pip install -r requirements.txt \
    && apt-get purge -y --auto-remove gcc python3-dev build-essential
```

you can use multistage builds if you don't require git in your final image you can remove in final stage

Also if possible you can use alpine version also.

Comment: thanks for looking into this. I can pretty much use alpine but I believe it does not support the apt-get commands

Comment: in that it's better to use multistage and move dependency packages to other steps.

Comment: in multi-stage just move python wheels only and use it.

Comment: I have used multistage and updated the question with new dockerfile. It is coming around 1.7GB which I believe still more. I would appreciate if you can please have a look and suggest me. Thank you

Comment: i am not sure this build working for you or not as you also not copying python wheels from one stag to another stag and also on workdir in second stag. is it working ?

Answer (score 0):

Now the image is smaller:

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04 AS builder
RUN apt update -y
RUN apt install python3-pip -y
RUN apt install build-essential automake pkg-config libtool libffi-dev libgmp-dev -y
RUN apt install libsecp256k1-dev -y 
RUN apt install openjdk-8-jre-headless -y
RUN apt install git -y
RUN apt install libkrb5-dev -y
RUN apt install vim -y
RUN mkdir /opt/app
RUN chown -R root:root /opt/app
COPY ["requirements.txt","/opt/app/requirements.txt"]
SHELL ["/bin/bash", "-c"]
WORKDIR /opt/app
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt && apt-get -y clean all
RUN mkdir /opt/app/
RUN chown -R root:root /opt/app/
RUN cd /opt/app/
RUN git clone -b master https://bitbucket.org/heroes/test.git
CMD ["bash","/opt/app/bin/connect.sh"]
```

Comment: I have used multistage and updated the question with new dockerfile. It is coming around 1.7GB which I believe still more. I would appreciate if you can please have a look and suggest me. Thank you

Comment: Replace ```openjdk-8-jre``` by ```openjdk-8-jre-headless``` to get a smaller image

Comment: if you remove ```pip3 install -r requirements.txt``` which size do your image have then?

Answer (score 0):

Try disabling recommended packages of APT with `--no-install-recommends`, you can read more about it from [here](https://ubuntu.com/blog/we-reduced-our-docker-images-by-60-with-no-install-recommends).